# If $x = \tan\alpha$, then show $x^2 + 1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

let $\alpha = \arctan(x)$. Then tan( $\alpha$) = x

Can you show that

$$x^2 +1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

I see than $(\sin x)^2 + (\cos x)^2 = 1$ so

$$x^2 +1 = \frac{(\sin\alpha)^2 + (\cos\alpha)^2}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1+\tan^2\theta=\dfrac1{\cos^2\theta}$ is a high-school identity, a rewriting of *Pythagoras' identity*: $\;\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, dividing both sides by $\cos^2\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

$$1+\tan^2\alpha=\frac{\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 +1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$

$\tan^2 (\alpha) + 1 = \frac 1{\cos^2(\alpha)}$

$\frac {\sin^2 (\alpha)}{\cos^2 (\alpha)} + 1 = \frac 1{\cos^2(\alpha)}$

The rest is work and I don't work on memorial day. .... But $\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 1$ will maybe be useful.